# Speed java code by moving function to a thread of its own

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code in the far bottom becomes slow when calling `Moon m = new Moon();. 
to fix this I would like to put the following code in a thread or something so that the moonCalTimer exits quicker and returns values to other functions. any idea how put this in a thread or similar?

```
Moon m = new Moon();
isWaning = m.isWaning();     
fullMoon = MoonPhaseFinder.findFullMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
newMoon = MoonPhaseFinder.findNewMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Code:

```
Timer moonCalTimer = new Timer();
moonCalTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
@Override
public void run() 
{
try {

//other code here...
//other code here...
//other code here...

Moon m = new Moon();
isWaning = m.isWaning();     
fullMoon = MoonPhaseFinder.findFullMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
newMoon = MoonPhaseFinder.findNewMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());

} 

catch (Exception ex) 
{
Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


}
}, 0, 3600000);
```

Comment: You are only performing this calculation every hour - would it not be better to start the calculation a few seconds early rather than obscure the issue with threads?

Comment: this also runs on the start of the program hence taking up to 2 mins to return values.

Comment: @Ossama: But it won’t get faster when it runs in another thread. The availability of the first result will not change.

Comment: you are correct Mr Holger, I didn't think about this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that the code just go on you could do:

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
        Moon m = new Moon();
    }
}.start();
```

If you want to use the m object, what i think you possible want, you should create a new class that implements runable, pass the m and then call start.

Comment: This is what I was thinkinking about, but i just realise as Holger said, that once i start the new thread, the function will wait untill it returns, so this will not make it faster...

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the calculation in a `Future`. You would then create the future and start the calculation in its own thread and hand the `Future` back to the caller. This would allow the caller to get its `Future` result before the calculation is complete.

```
private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public Future<Boolean> isWaning(final Moon moon) throws IOException {
  return pool.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
      return moon.isWaning();
    }

  }
  );
}

public Future<Boolean> fullMoonFollowing(final Moon moon) throws IOException {
  return pool.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
      return MoonPhaseFinder.findFullMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
    }

  }
  );
}

public Future<Boolean> newMoonFollowing(final Moon moon) throws IOException {
  return pool.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
      return MoonPhaseFinder.findNewMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
    }

  }
  );
}
```